# How many pipelines has each CPU core got?

Tags: multicore, pipeline

everyone.

I have a question about the Pipeline.
How many pipelines has each CPU core in Multi-core Processor got?

For example, a Quad core processor has got four pipelines used by each core?, or each core shares a pipeline?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "it depends on the exact microarchitecture."

Most multi-core processors have complete or near-complete instruction pipelines for each physical core.

If a 'multi-core' processor has "symmetric multi-threading" (Intel calls this "Hyper-Threading"), then that typically means each physical core has two logical cores where the first part of the instruction pipeline is replicated, but there's only a single pipeline that's 'timesliced' for that physical core.

Some designs can share other functional units as well. For example, the AMD Bulldozer shares the SIMD pipeline between each pair of physical cores.